# Update background image without refresh angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hey everyone I am currently building a mobile app for my company and I have a angularjs function that is currently adding a css class based on whether it's day or night. It does what it's supposed to do perfectly by putting a day or night image based on whether it's day or night.

The issue I am running into is that when testing the app right before the clock let's say goes from 1:59 to 2 it doesn't change the background image until you refresh the page. I want it to automatically change the background image without having to refresh and can't seem to find a way to do it. I will link the code here!

Any help is appreciated as it has me completely stumped...

Here is what I have in my html.

```
<div class="dashboard-welcome" ng-class="{'hide-homescreen-image-landscape' 
: isLandscape, 'homescreenImageDay' : isDay, 'homescreenImageNight' : 
isNight }">
```

Here is where the function is being called

```
angular.module('starter').controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 
'jsBridge', 'authService', 'tierService', '$window', fnc]);

function fnc($scope, $interval, jsBridge, authService, tierService, $window) 
{
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function (event, viewData) {
        setOrientation();

        $scope.isDay = !isDayTime(1000);
        $scope.isNight = isDayTime(1000);
    });
```

Here is where the function is instantiated. Basically checking what time it is.

```
var isDayTime = function () {
        var h = new Date().getHours();
        if (h >= 14) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I can't supply all the code since this application is thousands of lines long but this is the working function as of now. Just need it to switch background images without refreshing using angularjs...

Comment: You can create a timer service that handle time logic and notify you every hour to update your image. You can communicate between service and controller.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that inside your div you are using an `background-image: url("...")`

I suggest you set up an object to hold a single $scope.isDay value instead of doing the calculation twice.

Also use the `$interval` service to check every nth millisecond to update your $scope.isDay value.

The code below works fine in dynamically changing a background image on a page using its CSS class.

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="data.isDay ? 'back1' : 'back2'"></div>
```

JS:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.data = {
    isDay: true,
    classVal: {
      one: 'text-danger',
      two: 'text-success'
    }
  };

  $interval(function() {
        $scope.toggleImage();
      }, 600);

  $scope.toggleImage = function() {
    $scope.data.isDay = ($scope.data.isDay ? false : true)
  };

  $scope.toggleImage();
});
```

Here is also a plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/NxRgL2bXzlqqsUrNkw9i?p=preview)